# How to get reply in dynamic-tcp-client

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-ip

I want to use [dynamic-tcp-client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client)
in my project as a dynamic-tcp-client. I want to get reply in this client,so I changed the interface ,add a retrun String.

> ```
> @MessagingGateway()
> public interface ToTCP {
>     @Gateway(requestChannel = "toTcp.input")
>     public String send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port);
> }
> ```

I want to get reply message from server

```
        ToTCP toTcp = context.getBean(ToTCP.class);
    String receive =toTcp.send("foo", "localhost", 1234);
```

now I get a waring
`Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor:`
I don't know how to add the reply-channel?

Answer (score 0):

The `TcpSendingMessageHandler` in the dynamic flow needs to be changed to a `TcpOutboundGateway` for request/reply messaging.